# Orchard.Alias.Implementation.Updater.AliasHolderUpdater - Exception during Alias refresh

Tags: nhibernate, timeout, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/473454

I want to start by saying I'm currently migrating from Orchard CMS 1.6 to 1.7.2. So it used to work in 1.6 but I'm now having issues with 1.7.2.

2 of my Content Types are having issues when creating items, they never finish saving and when I check the logs I get this:

```
Orchard.Alias.Implementation.Updater.AliasHolderUpdater - Exception during Alias refresh
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ select aliasrecor0_.Id as Id1829_, aliasrecor0_.Path as Path1829_, aliasrecor0_.RouteValues as RouteVal3_1829_, aliasrecor0_.Source as Source1829_, aliasrecor0_.Action_id as Action5_1829_ from Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord aliasrecor0_ where aliasrecor0_.Id>@p0 order by aliasrecor0_.Id asc ]
  Name:p1 - Value:48
[SQL: select aliasrecor0_.Id as Id1829_, aliasrecor0_.Path as Path1829_, aliasrecor0_.RouteValues as RouteVal3_1829_, aliasrecor0_.Source as Source1829_, aliasrecor0_.Action_id as Action5_1829_ from Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord aliasrecor0_ where aliasrecor0_.Id>@p0 order by aliasrecor0_.Id asc] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

When I stop it and view the site (anywhere really), it's entirely wrecked with this error:

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]
[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]

Line 162:            return criteria
Line 163:                .List<ContentItemVersionRecord>()
Line 164:                .Select(x => ContentManager.Get(x.ContentItemRecord.Id, _versionOptions != null && _versionOptions.IsDraftRequired ? _versionOptions : VersionOptions.VersionRecord(x.Id)))

Source File: d:\Projects\Office Ignite\Main-1.7\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs    Line: 162
```

I don't know why this is isolated with those two CTs. They don't have parts with custom tables or anything.

Any piece of information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please file a bug with as much information as you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, but it seems that problem is not related directly for my code.

I found two solutions for now:

1.) Taxonomy corruption problem https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20411

2.) Static is dirty and lock which is default in select statment is heavly used https://serverfault.com/questions/419997/the-wait-operation-timed-out-when-running-sql-server-in-hyper-v